# Ubunto Command run continously

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below command is running one time and saves abc.pcap to directory. I want the below command to run continous and make pcaps of five second but file names should be different, it continously make 5 sec pcaps untill I stop it.

```
from subprocess import run
       
command = 'tcpdump -i eno1 -w abc.pcap'
output = run(command, capture_output=True, shell=True, timeout=5).stdout.decode()
print(" capture packet for 5 seconds")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "one.py", line 17, in <module>
    output = run(command.format(str(file_counter)), capture_output=True, shell=True,timeout=5).stdout.decode()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 491, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1024, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1867, in _communicate
    self._check_timeout(endtime, orig_timeout, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1068, in _check_timeout
    raise TimeoutExpired(
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command 'tcpdump -i eno1 -w abc_0.pcap' timed out after 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple while loop should do the job

```py
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import time
    
command = 'tcpdump -i wlp2s0 -w capture_{}.pcap'

file_counter = 0 
while True:
    proc = Popen(command.format(str(file_counter)),shell=True)
    time.sleep(5)
    proc.terminate()
    print("Capture ",file_counter)
    
    
    file_counter += 1

print("Captured packet for 5 seconds")
```

I used `Popen` instead of `run` and switched the dump interface to wlp2s0 because that way I could test it, but your interface should be work too with this code.
Btw, you have to execute this program with **sudo** so that tcpdump has the permissions to access the interface.
Instead of having a counter you should probably have the time as/in the filename.

Comment: it's not working the command runs only one time and stops giving above exception

Comment: Ok I will have another look at it in a moment

Comment: yes, please....

Comment: I updated the code and it should work now

Comment: yeah  Thank you it is working